# If TextBox = 1 thru 3 Then?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

This is more of a code quality question. I have this line that I'm working with. `Len(TextBox.Text) = 1 Or Len(TextBox.Text) = 2 Or Len(TextBox.Text) = 3` Is there a simpler way of writing this? Like a sort of: `If Len(TextBox.Text) = 1-3`?

Comment: `If 1 <= Len(TextBox.Text) And Len(TextBox.Text) <= 3 Then...`

Comment: @A.S.H The logic is sound. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select case Len(TextBox.Text)
case 1 to 3
  ...
end select
```

Comment: Wow. I never knew of select case. Did some googling of it. It looks like a alternate to if statements correct?